# Count values in two tables when joining four

Tags: sql-server, join, count, substring

I have a MS SQL problem that I can't solve by own. Below are the tables.

```
AREAS
----------------
RA_NAME varchar
RA_DESC varchar

AD_Results
-------------------
AssetName varchar
Parent_Counter varchar (the RA Name is somewhere within that field)

tblAssets
-----------
AssetID int

tblADComputers
----------------
AssetID int
OU varchar (the RA Name is somewhere within that field)
```

I had like to read the table AREAS with the RA Name and the description and count the number of AssetNames in AD_Results based on their RA and then count also AssetIDs in tblAssets also based on the RA Name.

The common "key" is the RA Name but it is not a key field in these tables; in fact is is a substring of an ordinary field.

Two single queries work fine, combining them to one gives insane high values in RA_AD_Objects.

I tried to get a list like that

```
RA_NAME RA_DESC RA_AD_Objects   RA_LS_Push
RA001   X01-01  549909          279
RA002   X02-02  635             0
RA004   X03-04  259306          409
```

My query looks like that:

```
 CREATE View AD_LS_CNT AS
 SELECT
        AREAS.RA_NAME
    ,   AREAS.RA_DESC
    ,   COUNT(CASE
                WHEN CharIndex('/RA', AD_Results.[Parent Container]) > 1
                THEN
                SubString(AD_Results.[Parent Container], CharIndex('/RA', AD_Results.[Parent Container]) + 1, 5)
                When CharIndex('/SH', AD_Results.[Parent Container]) > 1
                THEN
                SubString(AD_Results.[Parent Container], CharIndex('/SH', AD_Results.[Parent Container]) + 1, 5)
                ELSE
                'N.A.'
              End) AS RA_AD_Objects
    ,   COUNT( DISTINCT tblAssets.AssetID) AS RA_LS_Push
FROM AREAS
JOIN AD_Results ON CHARINDEX(AREAS.RA_NAME, AD_Results.[Parent Container]) > 0
LEFT JOIN tblADComputers ON CHARINDEX(AREAS.RA_NAME, tblADComputers.OU) > 0
LEFT JOIN tblAssets ON tblAssets.AssetID = tblADComputers.AssetID
GROUP BY AREAS.RA_NAME, AREAS.RA_DESC
ORDER BY AREAS.RA_NAME
GO
```

Comment: I edited out the bits on the end that weren't relevant, and the bit about the view was not needed as it can be seen in the question and whatever answer you get can be turned into a view

Comment: For counting rows why do you need  to extract string using substring function. you just need to check that string exist or not in target field.

Comment: May be you can try somthing like this SUM(CASE WHEN MATCHED THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a weekend of analysing I got the answer:

```
SELECT
        AREAS.RA_NAME
    ,   AREAS.RA_DESC
    ,   COUNT( DISTINCT AD_Results.Name) AS RA_AD_Objects
    ,   COUNT( DISTINCT tblAssets.AssetID) AS RA_LS_Objects
FROM AREAS
JOIN AD_Results ON CHARINDEX(AREAS.RA_NAME, AD_Results.[Parent Container]) > 0
LEFT JOIN tblADComputers ON CHARINDEX(AREAS.RA_NAME, tblADComputers.OU) > 0
LEFT JOIN tblAssets ON tblAssets.AssetID = tblADComputers.AssetID
GROUP BY AREAS.RA_NAME, AREAS.RA_DESC
ORDER BY AREAS.RA_NAME
GO
```

The whole COUNT(CASE ... mixed it up and it was not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(AREAS.RA_NAME, AD_Results.[Parent Container]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  RA_AD_Objects
```

Comment: Unfortunately this try shows the exact wrong numbers in counting/summing.

Comment: Can you share some test data. if its in excel file will help more.